# Reusing a StoredProcedureQuery with different parameter bindings

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, jpa-2.1

I'm creating a Named StoredProcedureQuery to access a stored procedure in my Postgres Database to update or insert values into a table.  I would like to reuse that StoredProcedureQuery because i have a set of data to update.  From trace logs and the content of the table it looks like the stored procedure is only being called the first iteration.  Is there a way to reuse a StoredProcedureQuery and rebind parameters?

```
private void updateValues(long id, List<Object> entities) {

    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery("update_data");

    for (Object entity : entities) {
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.setParameter("field1", entity.getField1());
        query.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```